# select by two condition and split by attribute

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

How can i retrieve data like in this image:

[image: in this image]

My database looks like this

```
SELECT trans_id, badge_id, user_id, comp_id, amount, cash, subsidy, trans_date
FROM trans_details
```

Comment: please provide more details, and bring that image here, instead of posting it somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the details query:

```
select user_id,count(1) as Txn,sum(amount),sum(cash),sum(subsidy)
from trans_details group by user_id;
```

For the totals query:

```
select count(1) as Txn,sum(amount),sum(cash),sum(subsidy)
from trans_details;
```